# I have list of adresses which i need to nslookup and send to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, nslookup

I am trying to do nslookup for addresses in my adrese.txt file and I would like to save them as .csv. Currently my biggest problem is that it only does nslookup for only one address and not all. It just exits with 0 and in my file there is only one adress. I am new to python and got no idea how to fix it. Also replacing .txt with csv in output file would be nice too.

edit: adress getting from text file works, second part is the problem, don't know why

```
import subprocess

f = open("adrese.txt")
next = f.read()
ip=[]

while next != "":
  ip.append(next)
  next = f.read()
file_ = open('nslookup.txt', 'w')
for i in ip:
  process = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  output = process.communicate()[0]
  file_.write(output)
file_.close()
```

Comment: Instead of nslookup, try [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why its doing this is because `while next != ""` is not doing what you want it to.

Instead, consider this:

```
import subprocess

with open('adrese.txt') as i, open('nslookup.txt', 'w') as o:
   for line in i:
     if line.strip(): # skips empty lines
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", line.strip()],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        o.write('{}\n'.format(proc.communicate()[0]))

print('Done')
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. Also my address getting from file is working, i checked it with print, but problem was in second part of the code, and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Your are actually not looping through all entries in your adrese.txt

```
ip = []
f = open("adrese.txt")
for line in f:
  ip.append(line)
f.close()

file_ = open('nslookup.txt', 'w')
for i in ip:
  process = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  output = process.communicate()[0]
  file_.write(output)
file_.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *check_call* and redirect the stdout directly to a file:

```
import subprocess

with open('adrese.txt') as f, open('nslookup.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, f):
        if line:  # skips empty lines
            subprocess.check_call(["nslookup", line],
                                    stdout=out)
```

You never use *stderr* so there is no point capturing it, if there are any non zero exit status you can catch a `CalledProcessError`:

```
 import subprocess

with open('adrese.txt') as f, open('nslookup.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, f):
        if line:  # skips empty lines
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(["nslookup", line],
                                         stdout=out)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                pass
```